# NodeJs-Cluster with Socket.IO and Namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, node-cluster

I am building a browsergame. The prototype is done and now i am thinking of how i can scale and host it. I already have a "gameserver", which currently handles one gamesession. A game session consists of a socketio connection to 8 players (max).

I would like to use e.g. [Node-Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to have multiple "gameservers" in the same docker-container, in which each gameserver should handle one ore more gamesessions, so that all cores of the cpu can be used.
A gamesession is just used by 8 players and the gamesessions should be isolated from each other.

As far as I know, Node-Cluster enables me to have all the subprocesses share the same port.
I thought of having a namespace for each gamesession (e.g. an ID in the browser to which the players connect anyways - The goal is: you get an URL which you sent to a friend in order to invite him, similar to e.g. skribble.io - https://localhost/?gameid=1234). So in my case, joining a namespace is basically the same as joining a game.

My goal is to have multiple of these docker-containers, and use a reverse proxy to route the incoming connection to the correct container, that handles the game, specified in the url.
But the problem here is, that i do not know, how i can forward the connection to the correct subprocess of the cluster.

so in the end it should look like following:

```
 GameServerMaster [Maps ids to processes like: [ClusterNode1:[id1,id2,..]}
   - GameServerClusterNode1
     - GameSession1 [id1 io.off("/id1")]
     - GameSession2 [id2 io.off("/id2)]
     - ....
   - GameServerClusterNode2
     - GameSession3 [id3 io.off("/id3")]
     - GameSession4 [id4 io.off("/id4)]
     - ....
```

I have found [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis), but this seems a bit overpowered, because there is no broadcast - each game is isolated. (and also i do not want to host redis just for this usecase)

Also, i have found [sticky-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-sticky-session), but by using this i do not know how to forward the incoming connection to the correct process, i think it just load-balances them, which is bad, because it must be routed to the one that actually handles the requested gamesession - but i think i need something like that anyways, or am i?

Is what i am doing (or planning to do) even the right approach? Do you have any suggestions in terms of technology or architecture?

Would it be better to throw away the whole clustering part and just have the docker-container handle one "node", that handles these multiple gamesessions?

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same situation, and I came out with the following solution.

#### Idea:

You fork new process with the cluster module on different port.
And with the master process you act like a router.

#### Example:

```
Before player joins a room, he asks the router,
(broadcast) where is room 123. The router asks his subprocesses
which of them hosts room 123, and forwards the result (eg. port 3001)
 to the client. The client then connects to the exact process.
```

#### Problems:

```
If more than one subprocess has the same roomId, there will be a conflict, 
but I guess you will figure out a way to avoid this, 
even tho the probability for this to happen is very low.
```

Note to mention is that this solution is to use all the **cores** of your machine, but not a solution to distribute to multiple machines.

If you want to distribute it to multiple machines, you should reconsider Redis as your first choice.

Comment: thank you for you comment. i was also thinking about that, but i also thought, that opening a port range on a docker container would just be the result of bad architecture, especially when node-cluster provides the port sharing feature. but i guess, this is probably still the most reliable solution, because it does not require additional dependencies.